# bigquery - how to set a destination table when the response is too big

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a bigquery data query, with AllowLargeResults = true, but it fails on exception for "response is too big" I read that I need to set a destination table. how do i do this in the code? Is there something I do wrong?

```
queuedJob = m_bigQueryService.Jobs.Insert(jobBody, oTask.ProjectName).Execute();
queuedJob.Configuration.Query.AllowLargeResults = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the destination table in the jobBody. Your code doesn't help to answer the question.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs

This links explain how to specify the job correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a destination table :

```
var jobConfig = new JobConfigurationQuery { Query = oQueryTask.QueryString, CreateDisposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED", AllowLargeResults = true, DestinationTable = new TableReference { DatasetId = oQueryTask.DataSet, ProjectId = oQueryTask.ProjectName, TableId = "tst1" } };
```

Comment: can you provide a full example? how do you use the job config inside of your Jobs.Insert()?

Answer (score 0):

```
var creds = GoogleCredential.FromJson(credsJson);
var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId, creds); 

var query = "SELECT name as Name FROM `dev.mytable`";

TableReference destination = client.GetTableReference("your_dataset", "destination_table_name");

BigQueryJob job = client.CreateQueryJob(query,
                    null, // No parameters
                    new QueryOptions { DestinationTable = destination });

// Wait for the job to complete.
job.PollUntilCompleted();
```